# Manually resolve Swift package dependencies

Tags: swift, package, package-managers

I have an Xcode project with a reference to a Swift Package within a github server.
From the local machine I am working on, I can not access the server, but I can copy the package from another network ( into a usb thumb-stick for instance ) and carry it over to my local machine.

My question is, once I have a copy of the repo, how can I manually added to my project so it stops trying to get it from the network?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the path from where the package is being fetched in `Package.swift` file.

```
let package = Package(
    name: "AutoLayoutProxy",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "../AutoLayoutProxy", from: "1.0.0")
        //.package(path: "../AutoLayoutProxy") // is also fine
    ]
)
```

Comment: I am going to Add package dependency and try to add : *file:///Users/Matias-Barrios/Projects/MyPackageFolder* but it does not add it. Is the package supposed to be a folder or a zip?

Comment: When I am trying as above, I get a popup windows stating "An Unkown error occurred"

Comment: It should be a swift package. This means the directory folder you are pointing to should contain a Package.swift file.